# i'm stuck with alpha-beta pruning algorithm implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, alpha-beta-pruning

I'm trying to implement **Game AI** for **9Men's Morris game.**

So far, i have the **board** represented like this:

```
    public class board 
    {
          public      node []gNode      = null;
          ... // so the table has 24 nodes, for 9 men morris game:
          gNode = new node[24];
          ...
          int evaluateBoard(); // evaluates the current board (tokens)
    }
```

ok, now every **node** is represented like so:

```
    public class node 
    {
     node() // constructor
     {     ...       }

     // setting current node's neighbours (maximum 4 neighbours)
     void setNeighbours(int left, int right, int top, int bottom)
     {      ...      }

     short      gOccupiedByTeam = renderer.TEAM_NOTEAM; // info if this node is occupied by a token (and a wich team this token belongs to) 
     short    []gNeighbourId    = null; // info about this node neighbours (can be max. 4 in a 9Men's morris game)
     short      gInternalID     = -1;   // board's IDs (from 0..23)
     short      gTokenID        = -1;   // this node can be occupied by a token.  (from 0 .. 8) -see below the token class.
     short      gNodeScore      = -1;   // a dummy node score.
     vector3    gLocation       = null; // 3d coordinates for this node.


    }
```

and a **token** looks like this:

```
public class token 
{
   token(vector3 startpos, short nodeId) // Constructor.
   {     ...     }


   public   physx       gPhysX      = null;  // 3d coordinates , velocity , accel. for this Token.
   public boolean       bIsAlive    = false; // is this token alive ? (or eliminated?)
   public boolean       bFormsMill  = false; // does it form a Mill?

   public short         gNodeID     = -1; // "link" this token with a gNodeID (when placing a token on current board). See above the node class. This represents a link ID to that node.
   public short         gTokenMill1 = -1; // used when this token forms a mill (with gTokenMill1  token!)
   public short         gTokenMill2 = -1; // same.

}
```

and Here is my Alpha-Beta pruning algorithm  implementation where **I'm stuck** :

```
public int getBestMove(board board, int depth, int alpha, int beta, boolean bIsPlayer)
{
    // if depth reached, return current's board's Evaluation (a score).
    if (depth == 0) return board.evaluateBoard(bIsPlayer);

    // is it Player's turn ? (max?)
    if (bIsPlayer)
    {
        // QUESTIONS: 
        // retrevie all possible "boards" below ! (all new possible token moves)
        // 1. here i should generate a new board with 1st possible move (for player token1) ?? ... then a second new board with 2nd possible move still for token1 ? .. and so on until no possible moves for token1?  
        //   (remembering that a token can move in 4 available spots - wich are a neighbour?) 
        // 
        // 2. the problem is that if i generate 4 new boards as per token 1 above let's say, then it will "eat" lot of memory for all 18 tokens and a function recursion depth of 5 for example, right ? 
        // 3. how do i fix point 2? 


        ArrayList<board> possible_boards = board.getAllPossibleBoards();

        // 4. ok, some possible boards were generated, loop thru them starting with the first one and calling recursively this function, is it right ?
        for(board iterator: possible_boards)
        {
            alpha = Math.max(alpha, getBestMove(iterator, depth - 1, alpha, beta, !bIsPlayer));

            if (beta < alpha)
            {

                break;
            }
        }

        // 5. how do i return best move to main calling function ? (wich token is it best move from all of these board's moves ?
        return alpha;
    }
    else
    {
        ArrayList<board> possible_boards = board.getAllPossibleBoards();

        for(board iterator: possible_boards)
        {

            beta = Math.min(beta, getBestMove(iterator, depth - 1, alpha, beta, !bIsPlayer));


            if (beta < alpha)
            {
                break;
            }


        }

        return beta;
    }


}
```

OK, this is my function so far. 
I Don't know even if **I'm on the right track** ??!

What's wrong in my function?
Please answer my above questions (1 to 5 in the getBestMove() function).

Thank you in advance and please escuse my language mistakes (my english it's not so good)

---

Thank you so much **saeedn** for your reply !!

I thought nobody will ever answer me :). I really helps me understand what's happening i think.

So,  **CheckWinner( *bool* )** will check if current player has a very good advantage (like **winning** or a **very good move** like blocking opponent,etc) at this *depth* so far, and if so then return a **BIG** score for current player. All of this because nor the player or the oponent will try to Win(**a big score**) every turn, right?

Otherwise if *depth*=0 then return a evaluation (score) of the current selected Board (**int evaluateBoard()**), allright.

After this, then I must generate a single board (with a single token posible move):

```
   while( board.generateNextPossibleBoard(nextBoard) ) // board generated and stored in "nextBoard". Also check if it is a valid board or no more boards to generate further.
```

Ok, having now a new generated board, recurse and if a better board (board with a better **SCORE**) is found then save current board to chosenBoard. If not then cutoff and return (don't check further down the tree).

Thanks again so much saeedn !!!

Comment: So just to be sure, this is for a minimax algorithm right?

Comment: Yes, minimax alpha-beta pruning . Thanks for the quick reply. I'm confused what parameters to pass to getBestMove() ? as a  node ? as a token ? here i'm sending as a board! .. and how to generate next-possible-moves(boards) is it what im doing correct so far?

Comment: Generate all possible boards with you alpha-beta tree. Then evaluate ending nodes (boards) with a "EvaluateBoard" function evaluating the score of a board (You determine how you wanna give a score according to your AI's disposition of pieces). Then you take the best board of them all (according to its score). Then the next move will be the move leading to the best of the possible boards.

Comment: Thanks Francis. Oh, it seems that what i've did above it's correct. But dont know for sure if i should generate a board for token1, then a second move still for token1 ..and so on until no moves for token1. after that ill continue with a board for token2 same as i did for token 1  ??

Answer (score 2):

Generally your code is ok, but there are some points you should have in mind.

First of all you should check if the node (here a board) is final or not (someone won the game), then check for depth equal to zero. And if someone won in that state, you may want to return a big value (for winning max player) and a small value (for winning min player), for exmaple MAXINT and MININT respectively.

To avoid high memory consumption, do not generate all possible board. Generate one board and do a recursive call for that and then generate another one and search for that and so on. This way you just use memory for one state in each stack frame. This is crucial in searches with high branch factor!

Finally you should record the board updating score of max player (where you update alpha).

see my pseudo code for more clarification:

```
if ( board.checkWinner(bIsPlayer) ) return board.evaluateBoard(bIsPlayer);

// if depth reached, return current's board's Evaluation (a score).
if (depth == 0) return board.evaluateBoard(bIsPlayer);

board chosenBoard;    
if (bIsPlayer)
{
    // You should implement this method, or write your board generation code here
    // returns false if no more boards could be generated
    board nextBoard;
    while( board.generateNextPossibleBoard(nextBoard) )
    {
        int v = getBestMove(iterator, depth - 1, alpha, beta, !bIsPlayer));

        if ( v > alpha )
        {
            alpha = v;
            chosenBoard = nextBoard;  // return this chosenBoard by reference ;)
        }

        if (beta < alpha)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return alpha;
}
else
{
    // The same for beta except you don't need to update chosenBoard :)
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but shouldn't board.evaluateBoard(bIsPlayer); be board.evaluateBoard(root_color) ?

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden It depends on how `evaluateBoard` is implemented. According to OP's code, it should be `board.evaluateBoard(bIsPlayer)`.

Comment: well if you do number_of_queens[current_player] - number_of_queens[opponent_of_current_player] then it should be bIsPlayer? sorry that I nag so much but I want to know it 100% sure, then I'll adapt to wikipedia page so that others can now it for sure too.
thanks by the way :-)

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden I don't know about the target game! and my suggestions are general ideas of alpha-beta implementation. Here you can encapsulate procedure of evaluating board in a function. If you think `evaluateBoard` has a wrong input parameter, please mention it in a comment on original post, so the author get notified and answer your concern :)